# how to trigger the dropdown action of a 'dropdown list'?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

Is it possible that i can trigger the dropdown of a dropdownlist by other elements?

for example, when click a button, a dropdown list will drop down.

please suggest how to do it in plain js withouting using any js framework, thanks

Comment: You can perform the click event to a dropdownlist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot programatically drop down a drop-down-list (select list) using JavaScript.

Comment: If you used a jquery plugin style drop-down-list, that simulates a drop-down-list you may have control over that to drop it down.